# Stripes in my laptop Dell Vostro 5468 screen. What to do with that?

Tags: dell-vostro

It suddenly appears on laptop screen and external monitor. I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
What can I do to remove them?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; nor details as to if this is a new install, an upgrade occurred, or some change was made in the last session before this issue appeared that now needs reverting.

Comment: I added more details in question.

Comment: Do they appear if you boot from the Ubuntu installation USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option?